# Success message after password recovering failed

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem,

When i press submit button it should display in changepassword.php?success message that change is success but it shows me "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found"

This is my code:

```
    <?php 
    include 'php_script/init.php';

    if (empty($_POST) === false){
        $required_fields = array('current_password', 'password', 'password_again');
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
            if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true){
                $errors[] = 'Trebate ispuniti sva polja';
                break 1;
            }
        }

        if (md5($_POST['current_password']) === $user_data['password']){
            if (trim($_POST['password']) != trim($_POST['password_again'])){
                $errors[] = 'Lozinke se ne poklapaju';
            }else if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
                $errors[] ='Vaša nova lozinka mora sadržavati barem 6 znakova';
            }
        } else{
            $errors[] = 'Vaša trenutna lozinka je netočna';
        }
    }
    ?>




<?php
            if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){
                echo 'Vaša lozinka je promijenjena';
            }else{

                if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
                    change_password($session_user_id, $_POST['password']);
                    header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
                }else if (empty($errors) === false){
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }}
            ?>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>Trenutna lozinka:<br><input type="password" name="current_password"/></li>
                    <li>Nova lozinka:<br><input type="password" name="password"/></li>
                    <li>Ponoviti lozinku:<br><input type="password" name="password_again"/></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Promijeni"/></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: your action="" is empty? where do you submit your form to?

Comment: @trainoasis yes because it is in same file

Comment: You are obviously not getting to the same page if 404 is returned. Make sure you are

Comment: @trainoasis where is my error? I set Location in the same changepassword.php file

Comment: in the form you are using POST method and you write GET in this if `(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){` is that correct??

Comment: @CoDe MurDeRer if i write POST it's the same

Comment: why do you reload the page just for the display of a confirmation message. Display the text directly. When you use the `header()` command your `$_POST` will be empty.

Comment: @RST how should I display text directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You submit the form, check all the information for errors, then you want to reload the page again to display the errors, or the "succesfully changed" message.

The last reload is not necessary.

Change this:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){
                echo 'Vaša lozinka je promijenjena';
            }else{

                if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
                    change_password($session_user_id, $_POST['password']);
                    header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
                }else if (empty($errors) === false){
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }}
            ?>
```

to

```
<?php
                if ( ! empty($_POST) && empty($errors) ){
                   // not empty $_POST means we did some validation
                   // empty $errors, no errors were found while validating
                    change_password($session_user_id, $_POST['password']);
                    echo 'Vaša lozinka je promijenjena';
                }
                if ( ! empty($_POST) && ! empty($errors) ){
                    // not empty $_POST means we did some validation
                    // errrors were found let's display them
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your condition is wrong here,

change this

```
   if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) && ($_GET['success'] != "")){
```

or

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) && !empty($_GET['success'])){
```